# How to add images as an attribute to Rails 4 ActiveRecord model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, postgresql, activerecord, paperclip

I am building a recipe website.  For this website, I would like to have pictures with each Recipe and with each RecipeStep.  It will be a predetermined number, 3 images per Recipe and 1 image per RecipeStep.  I have only used Paperclip for avatar images before and am not sure what magic it does behind the scene in order to store these images.

What is the best way to build a relationship for images and recipes (or any model for that matter) in Rails 4 with Postgresql?

Comment: I'd store them as `bytea` fields in a side-table in Pg.